# After changing the image, the CSS style of the image is invalid

Tags: css, frontend

At first, my picture is like this, the avatar can be displayed in the center。

[image]

And the CSS code for class .avator is:

```
.idx_box .search_box .avator {
  width: 0.64rem;
  height: 0.64rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #feb5b4;
}
```

The CSS code for `img` is：

```
.idx_box .search_box .avator img {
   width: 0.3rem;
   height: 0.3rem;
   margin: 0 auto;
   -webkit-transform: translateY(45%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(45%);
  transform: translateY(45%);
}
```

where 1rem is equal to 100px；

However, when I changed the picture, the horizontal centering effect didn't work. The CSS code is still the same as above and has not changed. I can't find the reason. Picture as shown：

[image]

Thanks！

Comment: can you also add the HTML for your CSS? Images don't count. Best would be if you can create a snippet in your question so we can see your problem.

Comment: `.img` class is removed.

Comment: Thanks,I wrapped the image in a div.Then fill the box with the picture to achieve the effect.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this 'text-align:center;' to .avator class.

I think the reason it didnt work, was because the image wasnt centrally aligned in the first instance. This showed in the second instance when you put a smaller image.

By the way, this 'margin: 0 auto;' inside the img, does nothing.

Comment: Thanks,I wrapped the image in a div.Then fill the box with the picture to achieve the effect.